# Converting datetimeindex to timestamp for pd.date_range

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have two lists:

"max_" consists of datetime types:

```
2012-04-20 00:00:00
2012-11-29 00:00:00
2013-11-22 00:00:00
```

"min_" , consists of datetimeindex:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-07-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2013-02-05', '2013-10-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
```

My expected output is to take a range from each max value to its respective min value, for example, the first one would be range (2012-04-20 to 2012-07-11). I've tried:

```
pd.date_range(max_, min_)

TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2012-07-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp
```

I'm not sure how to get around the conversion part, additionally, I'd like to have only the first value for the min_ lists (and ignore any additional).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just specify items in your lists that you want to create the range on:

```
pd.date_range(min_[0],max_[0])
```

If you are trying to print the ranges:

```
for date in max_:
    print (pd.date_range(min_[0],max_[date])
```